Trouble with establishing bluetooth connection using BlueCove library in Java
I'm trying to write a server/bluetooth receiver application that will receive data via bluetooth and (for now) print it to the console, but I'm stuck on the bluetooth connection. I use the BlueCove library. Note: this is not an android application but will be used for a desktop app
Problem: streamConnNotifier.acceptAndOpen() method starts and never stops executing. It doesn't throw exceptions or errors, it just loops endlessly and doesn't go any further with the code. Even if client/bluetooth sender app sucessfully connects over bluetooth, this app is not responding and keeps on running/stuck on said method.
Originally, the method was called as follows: StreamConnection connection streamConnNotifier.acceptAndOpen() without a thread, but when the program reached that line, it would just keep running endlessly and I couldn't debug it.
I then transferred that to the thread connThread with the aim of executing streamConnNotifier.acceptAndOpen() to run in the background and for program to continue working after connThread.join(), which waits for the thread to finish, and to make it easier to debug. But the apps keeps on running endlessly.
Info I got from debugging: RemoteDevice dev = RemoteDevice.getRemoteDevice(connection.get()); -> on this method it tells me that connection = null, which is very strange because:  if (connection.get() == null) { System.out.println("Connection is null"); }, that is inside thread, is not executed.
How can a connection be null if it is initialized before entering the thread: AtomicReference<StreamConnection> connection = new AtomicReference<>(); and then set inside the thread: connection.set(streamConnNotifier.acceptAndOpen());?
No matter using the thread or not, app always gets stuck on streamConnNotifier.acceptAndOpen() keeps running endlessly.
I've been struggling with this for a week now and it just won't work no matter what I try. All suggestions welcome!
     UUID uuid = new UUID("1101", true);
        String connectionString = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid +";name=SampleSPPServer";

        StreamConnectionNotifier streamConnNotifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier)Connector.open( connectionString );

        AtomicReference<StreamConnection> connection = new AtomicReference<>();
        Thread connThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("Server Started. Waiting for clients to connect...");
                connection.set(streamConnNotifier.acceptAndOpen());
                if (connection.get() == null) {
                    System.out.println("Connection is null");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        connThread.start();
        System.out.println("waiting connThread to finish");
        connThread.join();
        System.out.println("connThread finished");

        RemoteDevice dev = RemoteDevice.getRemoteDevice(connection.get());
        System.out.println("Remote device address: "+dev.getBluetoothAddress());
        System.out.println("Remote device name: "+dev.getFriendlyName(true));

